Generate dummy or insert missing data for selective dates in SQL with a custom logic
I have a table as follows (trnxn):
col_1  col_2    col_3     t_date      open_qty     recept   issue   close_qty   rank
  p1    m1                 03-Sep-24    0.00          15      5      10.00      1
  p1    m1                 15-Sep-24    10.00         20      10     20.00      2
  p1    m1                 22-Sep-24    20.00         5       10     15.00      3
  p1    m2      psp1       01-Sep-24    30            0       0      30.00      1
  p1    m2      psp1       05-Sep-24    30.00         12      20     22.00      2
  p1    m2      psp1       06-Sep-24    22.00         5       8      19.00      3
  p1    m2      psp1       18-Sep-24    19.00         23      20     22.00      4
  p1    m2      psp1       30-Sep-24    22.00         0       22     0.00       5

Below are some important points
close_qty = open_qty + recept - issue
previous day's closing becomes next day's opening

As it can be seen that for a given combination of col_1,col_2 and col_3, the data is present only for few dates.
The question is:
How to plot / generate dummy records for all dates keeping the above two points /logic in mind?
Below table shows the expected output for m1 and p1.
col_1   col_2   col_3   t_date      open_qty    recept  issue   close_qty
p1       m1             03-Sep-24     0.00        15      5       10.00 
p1       m1             04-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             05-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             06-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             07-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             08-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             09-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             10-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             11-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             12-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             13-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             14-Sep-24     10.00        0      0       10.00 
p1       m1             15-Sep-24     10.00        20     10      20.00 
p1       m1             16-Sep-24     20.00        0      0       20.00 
p1       m1             17-Sep-24     20.00        0      0       20.00 
p1       m1             18-Sep-24     20.00        0      0       20.00 
p1       m1             19-Sep-24     20.00        0      0       20.00 
p1       m1             20-Sep-24     20.00        0      0       20.00 
p1       m1             21-Sep-24     20.00        0      0       20.00 
p1       m1             22-Sep-24     20.00        5      10      15.00 
p1       m1             23-Sep-24     15.00        0      0       15.00 
p1       m1             24-Sep-24     15.00        0      0       15.00 
p1       m1             25-Sep-24     15.00        0      0       15.00 
p1       m1             26-Sep-24     15.00        0      0       15.00 
p1       m1             27-Sep-24     15.00        0      0       15.00 
p1       m1             28-Sep-24     15.00        0      0       15.00 
p1       m1             29-Sep-24     15.00        0      0       15.00 
p1       m1             30-Sep-24     15.00        0      0       15.00 

As can be seen from the above output that from 3rd Sept aka the first day of the transaction till the last day of the month it populates / generates the data keeping issue and recept as 0 in the interim dates.
I am afraid I have not come up with any SQL code for this as a head start.
Any clue would be appreciated.
Update
I am trying the below code:
WITH transactions AS (
SELECT 
    col_1, 
    col_2, 
    col_3, 
    MIN(t_date) AS start_date,
    MAX(t_date) AS end_date
FROM 
    trnxn
GROUP BY 
    col_1,col_2,col_3

),
date_range AS (
-- Create a series of dates from the minimum transaction date to a 
fixed maximum date (e.g., September 30, 2024)
SELECT 
    t.col_1,
    t.col_2,
    t.col_3,
    t.start_date + (seq.n * INTERVAL '1 day') AS date_series
FROM 
    transactions t
JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) - 1 AS n
    FROM generate_series(1, 1000) -- Generate a series of numbers
) seq
ON t.start_date + (seq.n * INTERVAL '1 day') <= '2024-09-30'

-- Aggregate existing data to fill in the values
),
aggregated_data AS (
SELECT
    col_1,
    col_2,
    col_3,
    t_date,
    open_qty,
    recept_qty,
    issue_qty,
    close_qty,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_1,col_2,col_3 ORDER BY 
 t_date) AS rnk
  FROM
     trnxn
)

SELECT 
d.col_1,
d.col_2,
d.col_3,
d.date_series AS t_date,
coalesce(a.open_qty,LAG(a.close_qty,1) OVER()) AS open_qty

,COALESCE(a.recept_qty, 0) AS recept_qty
,COALESCE(a.issue_qty, 0) AS issue_qty

 ,coalesce(close_qty,lag(a.close_qty,1) 
 over()+coalesce(recept_qty,0)-coalesce(issue_qty,0)) as 
 close_qty
 FROM 
  date_range d
 LEFT JOIN 
   aggregated_data a 
 ON 
   d.col_1 = a.col_1 AND 
   d.col_2 = a.col_2 AND 
   d.col_3 = a.col_3 AND 
   d.date_series = a.t_date
ORDER BY 
  d.col_1, 
  d.col_2, 
  d.col_3, 
  d.date_series;

please see in DBFiddle
But the above code is not plotting the open_qty and close_qty on missing dates.
Any help would be appreciated.
